# In Javascript, how do you access key value data from an object in a mixed array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, key-value

my name's Mike and my question is two-fold:

1. How can I access the objects in my array so that they properly appear in my `question` prompt, and
2. How can I access the properties of the randomely selected object in an `if/else` statement?

I'm trying to make a simple flashcard program to help me memorize different kinds of sound equipment.  The list of equipment is large but I'm only including three different kinds to keep this example simple.  I want each object to have two properties: `answer` and `desc`.  This first part defines three objects, places them in an array, creates a variable for picking one of the array items randomely, and another variable for prompting the user for an `answer`:

```
var newFlash = function() {
    var A827 = {
        answer: "T",
        desc: "Multitrack Tape Recorder"
    };
    var LA2A = {
        answer: "O",
        desc: "Classic Leveling Amplifier"
    };
    var SonyC800G = {
        answer: "M",
        desc: "Tube Condenser Microphone"
    };
    var list = [A827, LA2A, SonyC800G];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    var question = prompt("What kind of equipment is " + list[rand] + "?");
};
```

Now, if I make my three items in my array all strings, they show up no problem in the `question` prompt correctly replacing `list[rand]` with the appropriate array item.  However, using objects in my array, my prompt says `"What kind of equipment is [object Object]?`.

My end goal is for the user to enter the appropriate one- or two-letter response (M for Microphone, C for Console, O for Outboard Gear, T for Tape Machine, S for Software, and CH for Computer Hardware) where upon entering the successful letter(s) yields an alert that displays both the object's `answer` and `desc`.  My n00b instinct tells me this second part should be an `if/else` statement in the form of

```
if (question == list[rand.answer]) {
    alert("Correct, Answer: " + list[rand.answer] + ", a " + list[rand.desc] + "!");
}
else {
    alert("Wrong, try again.");
}
```

but I'm very certain that this isn't the right way to access these object properties.

So, again, my question has two parts:

1. How can I access the objects in my array so that they properly appear in my `question` prompt, and
2. How can I access the properties of the randomely selected object in an `if/else` statement?

I'm sure some piece of logic is escaping me.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `var question = prompt("What kind of equipment is " + list[rand].desc + "?");`. `list[rand]` will yield you an object which has the structure `{answer: "", desc: ""}`, so you need to additionally access the description in your code.

Similarly, you want:

```
if (question == list[rand].answer) {
    alert("Correct, Answer: " + list[rand].answer + ", a " + list[rand].desc + "!");
}
else {
    alert("Wrong, try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the property of an Object in Javascript you use dot notation, as is common with many languages that have Objects.  `list` is an array of Objects, so when you type `list[rand]` you are returning one of those Objects.  Once you have an Object, you simply need to use the dot notation to access whatever property it is you require, in this case either `desc` or `answer`.

So instead of

`var question = prompt("What kind of equipment is " + list[rand] + "?");`

try

`var question = prompt("What kind of equipment is " + list[rand].desc + "?");`

Placing the property you are trying to access *outside* the bracket.  This solves your second question as well, simply change:

```
if (question == list[rand.answer]) {
    alert("Correct, Answer: " + list[rand.answer] + ", a " + list[rand.desc] + "!");
```

to:

```
if (question == list[rand].answer) {
    alert("Correct, Answer: " + list[rand].answer + ", a " + list[rand].desc + "!");
```

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujJ4n/) will help demonstrate.